# Fisher Information invariant by a specific reparameterization of the Exponential Distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics, exponential-distribution, parameterization, fisher-information, invariance

The exponential distribution can be parameterized in two common ways:
$$
f(x) = \lambda \exp(-\lambda x)
$$
where $E[X] = \frac{1}{\lambda}$ $\text{Var}[X] = \frac{1}{\lambda^2}$, or as
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{\beta} \exp(-\frac{1}{\beta} x)
$$
where $E[X] = \beta$ and $\text{Var}[X] = \beta^2$

When I calculate the Fisher Information using each of these parameterizations, I obtain $\dfrac{1}{\lambda^2}$ for the first parameterization and $\dfrac{1}{\beta^2}$ for the second.

Is there an intuitive reason why this is true? I would have assumed them to be inverses of each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the impact of the Jacobian term for this specific transform (and only for this specific transform): denoting $I_1$ the information on $\beta$ and $I_2$ the information on $\lambda$
$$I_1(\beta)=I_2(\lambda(\beta)) \times \left(\frac{\text d\lambda}{\text d \beta} \right)^2=\frac{1}{\dfrac{1}{\beta^2}}\times\frac{1}{\beta^4}=\frac{\beta^2}{\beta^4}$$
Similar invariance properties can be found in other distributions by solving the differential equation
$$I_2(\lambda(\beta)) \times \left(\frac{\text d\lambda}{\text d \beta} \right)^2=I_2(\beta)$$
See for instance the Poisson distribution where the Fisher informations are the same functions for $\lambda$ and $\beta=1/\lambda$.

Comment: is this only true for exponential families?

Comment: invariance of Fisher information to one-to-one transformations

Comment: For any model with information matrix $I_2(\beta)$ such that the above equation allows for a solution in $\lambda$, this is true...